# CXF - ClassCastException (SEIStub/ClientProxy)

Tags: java, cxf, classcastexception

I'm trying to build a client jar file to access a webservice.  I'm including the jar in a servlet/war that makes the client webservice calls.  I'm getting the following error:

```
INFO: 2011 Apr 14 14:57:32,780 MDT [http-thread-pool-8181(4)] ERROR     my.package.ClientServlet - Caught exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(ClientProxy.java:93)
at my.package.Client.<init>(Client.java:54)
at my.package.ClientServlet.testService(TestServlet.java:118)
```

I came across this post http://yaytay.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/lsned-29-persuading-jdk-6-to-use-cxf-classes-rather-than-its-own-avoiding-seistub/ which says to fix the problem you need to include `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws` as a dependency, which I do.  So, that isn't the problem/solution in my case.

My client jar pom has these dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <cxf.version>2.3.3</cxf.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The servlet war contains the following in its lib:

```
asm-3.3.jar
bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cxf-api-2.3.3.jar
cxf-common-schemas-2.3.3.jar
cxf-common-utilities-2.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-core-2.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-ws-security-2.3.3.jar
cxf-tools-common-2.3.3.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
neethi-2.0.4.jar
my-client-cxf-1.0.jar
serializer-2.7.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.4.2.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar
stax2-api-3.0.2.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wss4j-1.5.11.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
xmlsec-1.4.4.jar
```

I've also read some posts that talk about a `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` file, but haven't been able to find any references that detail what it should be named, contain and placed.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to include a sun-web.xml (or glassfish-web.xml) file in the war WEB-INF. See [How to pick CXF over Metro on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064068/how-to-pick-cxf-over-metro-on-glassfish)

**EDIT**

Contents of glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN' 
    'http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd'>

<glassfish-web-app>
    <!-- Need this to tell Glassfish not to load the JAX-WS RI classes so it will 
        use the CXF ones instead -->
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: I swear to God, if this works for me, you've got some bounty rolling your way ;)

Comment: Can you post the xml files that worked for you? Or at least the relevant parts?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. I'm just glad my answer was useful to someone else since I've found the answers to many of my questions from SO.

Comment: Is there a way to do that programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

Remove JAX-WS Libraries from buildpath, so this can resolves my problem that is (`ClassCastException`) SEIStub to ClientProxy.

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails, you can use reflection to override the delegate of the service.

```java
        QName qName = new QName(wsTargetNamespace, wsName);
        service = new YourServiceScheduler(loc, qName);
        Field delegateField = Service.class.getDeclaredField("delegate");
        delegateField.setAccessible(true);
        ServiceDelegate previousDelegate = (ServiceDelegate)delegateField.get(service);
        if(!previousDelegate.getClass().getName().contains("cxf")) {
            ServiceDelegate serviceDelegate = ((Provider) Class.forName("org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl").newInstance())
                .createServiceDelegate(loc, qName, service.getClass());
            log.info("The " + getClass().getSimpleName() + " delegate is changed from " + "[" + previousDelegate + "] to [" +
                serviceDelegate +
                "]");
            delegateField.set(service, serviceDelegate);
        }
        port = service.getYourServiceSoap();
```

Comment: (relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364333/jax-ws-when-apache-cxf-is-installed-it-steals-default-jdk-jax-ws-implementat/ )

Comment: I am trying this, but I am getting: NoSuchField delegate

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right `Service.class`? The fully qualified name is `javax.xml.ws.Service`. I sure hope this implementation detail didn't change

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue while upgrading our application to Java 11. In the end it turned out that we had some weired dependency setup and two "conflicting" libs:

cxf-rt-frontend-simple vs. cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws

So I removed all the simple dependencies and replaced them with jaxws and now all is fine ->

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
 <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Credits to this blog post -> http://www.littlebigextra.com/exception-how-to-resolve-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-client-sei-seistub-cannot-be-cast-to-org-apache-cxf-frontend-clientproxy/

For further reading I recommend this thread on Java >8 migrations: [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis/48204154#48204154)

Answer (score 1):

I tried CXF in the past and came across strange exceptions like this one. I assume you already tried [CXF mailing list](http://cxf.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

I would try to go slow: start with a working example from the CFX distribution and make one change at a time until you get to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using constructor

```
Cebbcws ws = new Cebbcws();
CebbcwsPortType wsport = ws.getCebbcwsPort();
```

Invoke the service using `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.getClientFactoryBean().getServiceFactory().setWsdlURL(Cebbcws.WSDL_LOCATION);
factory.setServiceName(Cebbcws.SERVICE);
factory.setEndpointName(Cebbcws.CebbcwsPort);
CebbcwsPortType wsport = factory.create(CebbcwsPortType.class);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39251733/2686972

Answer (score 0):

This error also happened while migrating to sbt 1.3.6 with OpenJdk 11.

But acually I was using:

```
"com.sun.xml.ws" % "jaxws-ri" % "xxx"
```

and replacing with apache's jaxws fixes the error:

```
"org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs" % "3.3.0"
```