# JAX-WS = When Apache CXF is installed it "steals" default JDK JAX-WS implementation, how to solve?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I have a strange problem.

1. Using wsimport I generated als JAX-WS Code from a WSDL (in a dedicated eclipse java project). This works fine in JDK6 without any external dependencies (running in Eclipse)
2. I have second project where I once used Apache CXF. If I copy the Code described in 1.) into this project, suddenly not the JDK executes the JAX-WS stuff (files I generated), but rather Apache CXF.

How can I prevent Apache CXF "running" the JAX-WS stuff. (Problem is, CXF Fails to run the code...). I also completely do not understand how Apache CXF discovers these classes. I did not register them anywere?

Thank you very much!
Markus

Comment: Honestly, I'd be most interested in why CXF fails to run the code.   CXF is completely JAX-WS compliant so it should be a drop in replacement for the in-jdk jax-ws implementation.   Bug report?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Apache CXF (`cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-*.jar` to be precise) registers itself as a JAX-WS provider in the JVM. Inside the aforementioned JAR there is a file named: `/META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` with the following contents:

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

If you now look at `javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder#find` method you will discover that JDK searches the CLASSPATH for the presence of `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` file and falls back to default Sun implementation if not available. So you have two options to force fallback:

- either remove `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-*.jar` from CLASSPATH
- or override `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` file provided by CXF to point to fallback location

The second option is actually a bit easier. Simply create:

```
/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
```

file (assuming you are using Maven) with the following contents:

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

That's it, tested with `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint#publish`.

Comment: Hello Tomasz, thank you very much for your geneours and valuable help. It is very much appreciated!!! (Just in case you know this: Is it correct that I can either use JDK OR CXF? So there is no option to tell CXF to leave some of my classes/packages untouched and in the and use both somewho in parallel...) Thanks.

Comment: Your second option tells you how to configure JAX-WS to use CXF, what if I want JAX-WS to NOT use CXF?  Neither the META-INF/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider file nor the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws jar are on my classpath, so I can't figure out how to prevent CXF from becoming the JAX-WS provider

Comment: I was trying to make CXF run on WebLogic 11g 10.3.6 for a couple of days already - this was the key. It seems that the Provider file in META-INF (in EAR module) made the trick. I'm on the verge of tears. Thank you :-)

Comment: See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.html#provider()

Comment: Overriding `META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` doesn't always work for all servers like for Websphere where it forces it's own implementation on you.

Comment: This seems like a genuine classpath problem and seems to be working by simply placing the `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-*.jar` higher on the classpath (than the jar containing `javax.xml....` ). Then the `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` cxf one will surely get picked up. No ?

Answer (score 17):

For the default implementation put:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

inside /src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider

Answer (score 7):

I tried the other and I just couldn't make it work at all, so to set CXF if it was not set to CXF, I just override the delegate inside the service.

```
 try {
        loc = this.getClass().getResource(wsdlResource); 
        QName qName = new QName( wsTargetNamespace, wsName );
        service = new YourWS(loc, qName);
        Field delegateField = Service.class.getDeclaredField("delegate"); //ALLOW CXF SPECIFIC SERVICE DELEGATE ONLY!
        delegateField.setAccessible(true);
        ServiceDelegate previousDelegate = (ServiceDelegate) delegateField.get(service);
        if (!previousDelegate.getClass().getName().contains("cxf")) {
            ServiceDelegate serviceDelegate = ((Provider) Class.forName("org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl").newInstance())
                .createServiceDelegate(loc, qName, service.getClass());
            log.info("The " + getClass().getSimpleName() + " delegate is changed from " + "[" + previousDelegate + "] to [" +
                serviceDelegate +
                "]");
            delegateField.set(service, serviceDelegate);
        }
        port = service.getYourWSSoap();
```

Comment: I tried all the answers but for my application this is the only way the solved my problem , Thanks :)

Comment: (relevant question with same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31892206/2413303 )

Comment: The `Service.class` is `javax.xml.ws.Service`.

Answer (score 6):

The standard finding mechanisms don't seem to work nicely in OSGi (*).

There are two ways I've gotten to work forcing the service to pick up the CXF implementation of `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider`:

- the approach of setting `delegate` by reflection given in EpicPandaForce's answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31892305/109079)
- calling the lower-level `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`; this seems to avoid all calls to the `javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder` included with Java which is the root of the problem

Here is an example of the latter, for less intrepid coders who prefer not reflectively changing private fields:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.getClientFactoryBean().getServiceFactory().setWsdlURL(WinRmService.WSDL_LOCATION);
factory.setServiceName(WinRmService.SERVICE);
factory.setEndpointName(WinRmService.WinRmPort);
// factory.setFeatures(...);  // if required

Service winrm = factory.create(WinRm.class);        

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(winrm);
```

A couple of notes:

- Passing a `URL` as above, rather than the simpler `factory.setWsdlURL(String)` may be needed if the WSDL is a resource on the classpath (avoid unresolvable `bundle://...` URLs for classpath items)
- You may need additional bundles for features (such as addressing)

---

(*) *As for why the finding mechanisms don't work in most OSGi containers, check out this little bit of nasty in Oracle Java's `FactoryFinder`:*

```
private static final String OSGI_SERVICE_LOADER_CLASS_NAME = "com.sun.org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader";

private static boolean isOsgi() {
    try {
        Class.forName(OSGI_SERVICE_LOADER_CLASS_NAME);
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

OSGi = Glassfish?  Fishy indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case I had to use `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl` for JAX-WS stuff (creating webservice endpoints etc.) and `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl` for publishing endpoints on `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer`.

I managed to solve this by creating my own provider which extends `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` and using it instead of the default one.

```
package provider;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.EndpointReference;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
import javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider;
import javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceDelegate;
import javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class MyProvider extends Provider
{

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
public ServiceDelegate createServiceDelegate(URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName, Class serviceClass)
{
    try {
        return ((Provider) Class.forName("org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl").newInstance()).createServiceDelegate(wsdlDocumentLocation, serviceName, serviceClass.getClass());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Endpoint createEndpoint(String bindingId, Object implementor)
{
    try {
        return ((Provider) Class.forName("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl").newInstance()).createEndpoint(bindingId, implementor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Endpoint createAndPublishEndpoint(String address, Object implementor)
{
    try {
        return ((Provider) Class.forName("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl").newInstance()).createAndPublishEndpoint(address, implementor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public EndpointReference readEndpointReference(Source eprInfoset)
{
    try {
        return ((Provider) Class.forName("org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl").newInstance()).readEndpointReference(eprInfoset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public <T> T getPort(EndpointReference endpointReference, Class<T> serviceEndpointInterface, WebServiceFeature... features)
{
    try {
        return ((Provider) Class.forName("org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl").newInstance()).getPort(endpointReference, serviceEndpointInterface, features);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public W3CEndpointReference createW3CEndpointReference(String address, QName serviceName, QName portName, List<Element> metadata, String wsdlDocumentLocation, List<Element> referenceParameters)
{
    try {
        return ((Provider) Class.forName("org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl").newInstance()).createW3CEndpointReference(address, serviceName, portName, metadata, wsdlDocumentLocation,
                referenceParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Then simply create:

```
/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
```

file (assuming you are using Maven) with the following contents:

```
package.MyProvider
```