# jbossws webservice throwing exception from another spring based application

Tags: jbossws

I have picked an example from jboss ‘helloworld-ws’. I created a client spring based web application helloworld-ws-test. Then I created a webservice client through jboss webservice client (it also create one sample client with main method).
I deploy both applications in jboss 6.1-eap server. So if I try to access the webservice through sample client I am getting the output without any problem but when I copy the same code into helloworld-ws-test web application controller and try to access webservice I am getting the following exception.

```
11:51:55,025 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Could not complete request: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl$JBossWSServiceImpl.<init>(ProviderImpl.java:479)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:165)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57) [jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.0.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.jbossas.quickstarts.wshelloworld.helloworld.HelloWorldService_Service.<init>(HelloWorldService_Service.java:47) [classes:]
    at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.mvc.MemberController.displaySortedMembers(MemberController.java:20) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <HTML>
 at [row,col,system-id]: [4,0,"http://localhost:8080/helloworld-ws/HelloWorldService?wsdl"]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <HTML>
 at [row,col,system-id]: [4,0,"http://localhost:8080/helloworld-ws/HelloWorldService?wsdl"]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.throwUnexpectedEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:5532)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2720)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1250)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1144)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1071)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:234)
    ... 40 more

11:51:55,037 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/helloworld-ws-test].[jboss-as-kitchensink]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jboss-as-kitchensink threw exception: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <HTML>
 at [row,col,system-id]: [4,0,"http://localhost:8080/helloworld-ws/HelloWorldService?wsdl"]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.throwUnexpectedEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:5532)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2720)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1250)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1144)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1071)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl$JBossWSServiceImpl.<init>(ProviderImpl.java:479)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:165)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57) [jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.0.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.jbossas.quickstarts.wshelloworld.helloworld.HelloWorldService_Service.<init>(HelloWorldService_Service.java:47) [classes:]
    at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.mvc.MemberController.displaySortedMembers(MemberController.java:20) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
```

**WSDL**

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/quickstarts/wshelloworld/HelloWorld" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="HelloWorldService" targetNamespace="http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/quickstarts/wshelloworld/HelloWorld">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/quickstarts/wshelloworld/HelloWorld" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/quickstarts/wshelloworld/HelloWorld" version="1.0">
            <xs:element name="sayHello" type="tns:sayHello"/>
            <xs:element name="sayHelloResponse" type="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>
            <xs:element name="sayHelloToName" type="tns:sayHelloToName"/>
            <xs:element name="sayHelloToNameResponse" type="tns:sayHelloToNameResponse"/>
            <xs:element name="sayHelloToNames" type="tns:sayHelloToNames"/>
            <xs:element name="sayHelloToNamesResponse" type="tns:sayHelloToNamesResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="sayHello">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="sayHelloResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="sayHelloToNames">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="sayHelloToNamesResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="sayHelloToName">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="sayHelloToNameResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloToNameResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHelloToNameResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloToNamesResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHelloToNamesResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloToName">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHelloToName" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloToNames">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHelloToNames" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHelloResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sayHello">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHello" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="HelloWorldService">
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:sayHello" name="sayHello"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:sayHelloResponse" name="sayHelloResponse"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHelloToNames">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:sayHelloToNames" name="sayHelloToNames"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:sayHelloToNamesResponse" name="sayHelloToNamesResponse"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHelloToName">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:sayHelloToName" name="sayHelloToName"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:sayHelloToNameResponse" name="sayHelloToNameResponse"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:HelloWorldService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="sayHello">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="sayHelloResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHelloToNames">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="sayHelloToNames">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="sayHelloToNamesResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHelloToName">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="sayHelloToName">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="sayHelloToNameResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="HelloWorldService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding" name="HelloWorld">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/helloworld-ws/HelloWorldService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**HelloWorldService.java**

```
/*
 * JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
 * Copyright 2012, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
 * contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the 
 * distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,  
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.wshelloworld;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

/**
 * A simple example of how to setup a JAX-WS Web Service. It can say hello to everyone or to someone in particular.
 * 
 * @author lnewson@redhat.com
 */

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/quickstarts/wshelloworld/HelloWorld")
public interface HelloWorldService {

    /**
     * Say hello as a response
     * 
     * @return A simple hello world message
     */
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello();

    /**
     * Say hello to someone precisely
     * 
     * @param name The name of the person to say hello to
     * @return the number of current bookings
     */
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHelloToName(String name);

    /**
     * Say hello to a list of people
     * 
     * @param names The list of names to say hello to
     * @return the number of current bookings
     */
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHelloToNames(List<String> names);
}
```

**HelloWorldServiceImpl.java**

```
/*
 * JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
 * Copyright 2012, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
 * contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the 
 * distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,  
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.wshelloworld;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebService;

/**
 * The implementation of the HelloWorld JAX-WS Web Service.
 * 
 * @author lnewson@redhat.com
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "HelloWorldService", portName = "HelloWorld", name = "HelloWorld", endpointInterface = "org.jboss.as.quickstarts.wshelloworld.HelloWorldService", targetNamespace = "http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/quickstarts/wshelloworld/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldServiceImpl implements HelloWorldService {

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHelloToName(final String name) {

        /* Create a list with just the one value */
        final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add(name);

        return sayHelloToNames(names);
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHelloToNames(final List<String> names) {
        return "Hello " + createNameListString(names);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a list of names separated by commas or an and symbol if its the last separation. This is then used to say hello to
     * the list of names.
     * 
     * i.e. if the input was {John, Mary, Luke} the output would be John, Mary & Luke
     * 
     * @param names A list of names
     * @return The list of names separated as described above.
     */
    private String createNameListString(final List<String> names) {

        /*
         * If the list is null or empty then assume the call was anonymous.
         */
        if (names == null || names.isEmpty()) {
            return "Anonymous!";
        }

        final StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {

            /*
             * Add the separator if its not the first string or the last separator since that should be an and (&) symbol.
             */
            if (i != 0 && i != names.size() - 1)
                nameBuilder.append(", ");
            else if (i != 0 && i == names.size() - 1)
                nameBuilder.append(" & ");

            nameBuilder.append(names.get(i));
        }

        nameBuilder.append("!");

        return nameBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

**ClientSample.java**

```
package org.jboss.jbossas.quickstarts.wshelloworld.helloworld.clientsample;

import org.jboss.jbossas.quickstarts.wshelloworld.helloworld.*;

public class ClientSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("***********************");
            System.out.println("Create Web Service Client...");
            HelloWorldService_Service service1 = new HelloWorldService_Service();
            System.out.println("Create Web Service...");
            HelloWorldService port1 = service1.getHelloWorld();
            System.out.println("Call Web Service Operation...");
            System.out.println("Server said: " + port1.sayHello());
            System.out.println("Server said: " + port1.sayHelloToNames(null));
            //Please input the parameters instead of 'null' for the upper method!

            System.out.println("Server said: " + port1.sayHelloToName(null));
            //Please input the parameters instead of 'null' for the upper method!

            System.out.println("Create Web Service...");
            HelloWorldService port2 = service1.getHelloWorld();
            System.out.println("Call Web Service Operation...");
            System.out.println("Server said: " + port2.sayHello());
            System.out.println("Server said: " + port2.sayHelloToNames(null));
            //Please input the parameters instead of 'null' for the upper method!

            System.out.println("Server said: " + port2.sayHelloToName(null));
            //Please input the parameters instead of 'null' for the upper method!

            System.out.println("***********************");
            System.out.println("Call Over!");
    }
}
```

**MemberController.java**

```
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.mvc;

import org.jboss.jbossas.quickstarts.wshelloworld.helloworld.HelloWorldService;
import org.jboss.jbossas.quickstarts.wshelloworld.helloworld.HelloWorldService_Service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class MemberController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displaySortedMembers(Model model)  {

        System.out.println("***********************");
        System.out.println("Create Web Service Client...");
        HelloWorldService_Service service1 = new HelloWorldService_Service();
        System.out.println("Create Web Service...");
        HelloWorldService port1 = service1.getHelloWorld();
        System.out.println("Call Web Service Operation...");
        System.out.println("Server said: " + port1.sayHello());
        System.out.println("Server said: " + port1.sayHelloToNames(null));
        //Please input the parameters instead of 'null' for the upper method!

        System.out.println("Server said: " + port1.sayHelloToName(null));
        //Please input the parameters instead of 'null' for the upper method!

        System.out.println("Create Web Service...");
        HelloWorldService port2 = service1.getHelloWorld();
        System.out.println("Call Web Service Operation...");
        System.out.println("Server said: " + port2.sayHello());
        System.out.println("Server said: " + port2.sayHelloToNames(null));
        //Please input the parameters instead of 'null' for the upper method!

        System.out.println("Server said: " + port2.sayHelloToName(null));
        //Please input the parameters instead of 'null' for the upper method!

        System.out.println("***********************");
        System.out.println("Call Over!");

        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: After a bit more investigation it reveals that this is the problem with org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl. I have tried the solution provided in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364333/jax-ws-when-apache-cxf-is-installed-it-steals-default-jdk-jax-ws-implementat). but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put all the necessary jar files in your client. Please check out first and then check out your cxf jar file version for comfortable. Make sure you have defined the correct wsdl name (e.g "http: //something:7101/TestWSA/WsaWebServiceTest?WSDL") in your client class. Note, Check out your jar files version first. I think, it will work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not have any cxf specific jar in my maven and I deployed client web application in Glassfish and webserivce in JBoss. Client is working without any problem. But when I deploy the same client in JBoss it is throwing exception javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <HTML>

Comment: I think you need to check out your Client dependencies, sometimes those dependencies are already exist in JBOSS and some dependencies versions.