# Axis2 is "overriding" my JAXB web service

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-axis

So basically I have had a simple web service made with JAXB (As simple as Endpoint.publish()). It is working great. As soon as I try and use my service with another aplication that is itself using an Axis2 web service I cannot publish my web server anymore.
Since the second application was not made by me i cannot check the source code. I think that the AxisEngine is listening to my web server publishing and it wont let it be "created".

For example:

- Before this Axis2 application I would publish my webservice at http://ip:port/server and I was able to open the page http://ip:port/server?wsdl.
- Now I publish the server at the same address but when I open the page http://ip:port/server?wsdl I automatically get redirected to http://ip:port/services/ with the fault exception (The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)).

Comment: Although your text is very clear; it is not clear to me what exactly your question is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that I cannot access the ?wsdl page on my first web service as it is redirected to a /services/ page. This started happening when another application started making use of Axis2.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by following this steps on another question:

[JAX-WS = When Apache CXF is installed it "steals" default JDK JAX-WS implementation, how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364333/jax-ws-when-apache-cxf-is-installed-it-steals-default-jdk-jax-ws-implementat)