# Can we run both jaxws-rt and cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws jars?

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat, cxf

We are trying to integrate a web service which uses the `apache-cxf` implementation on a tomcat server. However, we already have another webservice running which uses the sun's library `jaxws-rt`. When both jars are added to `catalina.properties`, the first one declared will be loaded with priority, thus only allowing one of the webservices to run. Is there any workaround available to make webService1 use the `jaxws-rt` classes and webService2 to use the `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws` classes simultaneously?

The received error when jaxws-rt is loaded first is:

```
"com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy"
```

Comment: Fixed! I used EpicPandaForce's solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364333/jax-ws-when-apache-cxf-is-installed-it-steals-default-jdk-jax-ws-implementat/