# CXF - ClassCastException (SEIStub/ClientProxy) for webstart

Tags: java, cxf, java-web-start, jnlp, classcastexception

I have the same problem:
[CXF - ClassCastException (SEIStub/ClientProxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670343/cxf-classcastexception-seistub-clientproxy)

But it is standalone java application. Starting with webstart jnlp-file. Is there solution for webstart (something like delegate=false)?

Jnlp-file something like this:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://codebase.com/jars/">
  <information>
    <title>Java application</title>
    <vendor>Me</vendor>
    <icon href="splash.png" kind="splash"/>
    <offline-allowed/>
    <shortcut online="false">
      <menu submenu="Java application"/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="1024m"/>
    <jar href="xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar"/>
    <jar href="joda-time-1.6.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="xstream-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <jar href="xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-lang-2.5.jar"/>
    <jar href="swing-layout-1.0.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.10.jar"/>
    <jar href="cxf-2.7.10.jar"/>
    <jar href="geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="jaxb-api-2.2.6.jar"/>
    <jar href="jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar"/>
    <jar href="neethi-3.0.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="stax2-api-3.1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar "/>
    <jar href="hessian-4.0.7.jar"/>
    <jar href="waffle-jna-1.5.jar"/>
    <jar href="jna-3.5.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="platform-3.5.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="my.jar" main="true"/>
    <property name="jnlp.property" value="propertyValue"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="mypackage.MainClass"/>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell me if the cxf-2.7.10.jar is CXF all in one jar? 
If so , you don't need to include the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.10.jar.

Comment: standard cxf-2.7.10.jar about 7 Mb. ok. i remove cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.10.jar. thanx. but it is not about my problem i think